# How to get all rows with second highest value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this following table:

```
name  value  year
 A      1    2015
 A      2    2014
 A      3    2013
 B      1    2015
 B      3    2013
 C      1    2015
 C      2    2014
```

How can I get, for each name, the row with the second highest year, like this:

```
name  value  year
 A      2    2014
 B      3    2013
 C      2    2014
```

I tried the following query but no success:

```
select name, value, year
from TABLE_NAME
WHERE year IN (select year from TABLE_NAME order by year desc limit 1,1)
```

The previous query gives me this error: 
"SQL Error (1235): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' "

And I can't change the MySQL version (5.6.25) right now, because the solution is already in production.

Any help, please?

Comment: If the subquery ran, it would select the year `2014` and return all rows with `year=2014`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve n per group in MySQL is to simulate ROW_NUMBER. Note that this will only return one value per name.

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    value,
    year
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        t.name, 
        t.value,
        t.year,
        @rn := if(@prev = t.name, @rn + 1,1) as rn,
        @prev:=t.name

    FROM
        test_table as t
        JOIN (SELECT @Prev:= Null, @Rn := 0) as v
    ORDER BY 
        t.name,
        T.year desc) as t
WHERE
    rn = 2;
```

How this works.

- `SELECT @Prev:= Null, @Rn := 0` initializes two variables @Prev and @Rn.
- `@rn := if(@prev = t.name, @rn + 1,1) as rn` set the variable of @rn to either 1 or @rn + 1 depending on if @prev = t.Name and returns the value of @rn as the column rn
- `@prev:=t.name` sets the value of @prev equal to the current value of name

if you run

```
SELECT 
    t.name, 
    t.value,
    t.year,
    @prev = t.name as eval,
    @rn := if(@prev = t.name, @rn + 1,1) as rn,
    @prev:=t.name as prev

FROM
    test_table as t
    JOIN (SELECT @Prev:= Null, @Rn := 0) as v
ORDER BY 
    t.name,
    T.year desc
```

I would expect something like

```
name  value  year  eval  rn  prev
 A      1    2015  false  1  null
 A      2    2014  true   2  A
 A      3    2013  true   3  A
 B      1    2015  false  1  A
 B      3    2013  true   2  B
 C      1    2015  false  1  B
 C      2    2014  true   2  C
```

Wrapping into a subquery and the filtering for `rn=2` gives you the desired result

Comment: I got a little bit overwhelmed with the solution tho, where can I learn about HOW it worked? Thanks again.

Comment: @tfcsantana I added an expination

Answer (score 1):

My strategy is to use a grouping to find the highest years. Then join with the original table to remove the highest years. Finally do a grouping on the combined table to find the second highest year for each name. (If you need `value` you can do an `INNER JOIN` with the original table to find it.)

```
SELECT name, MAX(year)
FROM
    (SELECT name, year
        FROM TABLE_NAME) AS x1
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT name, MAX(year) AS year
        FROM TABLE_NAME
        GROUP BY name, year
    ) AS x2
    ON x1.name = x2.name AND x1.year <> x2.year
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name ASC ;
```

Comment: This would work although the nth highest would take n subqueries (if you wanted the "value" as well). It does have one advantage which depending on your requirements returns more than one record in the case of ties.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 select * from test_table where year = (select distinct year from test_table order by year desc limit 1,1)
```

Comment: just you need to add "distinct" in your inner query.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you rewrite it as a join:

```
select b.name, b.value, b.year
  from (select year
          from table_name
         order by year desc
         limit 1, 1) a
  join table_name b
    on b.year = a.year
```

Comment: I don't think this would return "B, 2013"

Comment: @Conrad: He. You're right. I didn't pay attention to the desired results. I only rewrote his query, which was not written properly either.