# MySql find maximum item by day for each id

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table like so:

```
id | day | item
---------------
 1 |   1 |    A
 1 |   2 |    B
 1 |   3 |    A
 2 |   1 |    C
 2 |   2 |    C
 2 |   5 |    B
 3 |   6 |    A
 3 |   7 |    C
```

I want to get the last item per id by day. So the output would be something like:

```
id | day | item
---------------
 1 |   3 |    A
 2 |   5 |    B
 3 |   7 |    C
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

I know how to do this when the last `day` is the same for all `id`s, but I don't know how to do it in the case when each `id` may have a different last day.

Comment: There are two approaches. One that uses max in a subquery. The other is to synthesize row_number (). It largely depends on how you want to deal with ties for the max

Comment: @ConradFrix can you write an answer example?

Comment: Here is an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38465135 where the difference is that you  would need  `where rn = 1`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
select table.* from table
join (select id, max(day) as day from table group by id) 
as m on m.id = table.id and m.day = table.day
```